# Placing HTML5 banner in WPF app

Tags: wpf, html

What are my options for placing several HTML5 banner ads in a WPF application? It seems that overlaying a few WebBrowsers (based on IE) might not be the wisest. The application does AllowsTransparency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for starters, you're going to need a web browser control for this (obviously).

Since the WebBrowser control in WPF and WinForms is based on the IE ActiveX control, you're stuck with whatever the end-user has installed on their computer, which may not support HTML5 very well.

Your best bet is to use [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/), which is nice .NET API on top of the open source Chromium rendering engine, which Google Chrome is based on.